# mounted local network synology folder : Input/Output error when tryign to write inside files

Tags: ubuntu, mount, synology, io

`/etc/fstab` mounts local network synology folder in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS like this:

`//<numeric synology ip>/<synology_folder_name> /home/<user>/<mount_folder> cifs credentials=/home/<user>/<file>,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0`

Inside `mount_folder`, I `touch text.txt` and then I `sudo nano text.txt`. I type text inside, hit `Ctrl-O + Enter` and I get `Error writing test.txt: Input/output error`. This happens with any write operation I try to perform inside this folder.

How do I solve this problem (maybe without contacting syno admin)?

Comment: beyond the case where the mounting user has write rights but the user running nano does not, this isn't going to be something you can solve locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the available space was used 100%